# Reachability to check the current status of my Host and No Need to use Notification Center

Tags: iphone, networking, reachability

I am using Reachability Code to check the network status of ip but currently i am using NSNotification Center. But i don't want to check like that. I need to check the network status only when i try to download something from my host.

Currently the internet connection is able to check properly but not able to check host reachability. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

1. Use Reachability to see if connectivity is available
2. Try to download a file from your site if there is a network
3. If you can't download the file, you'll get an error - deal with it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

[Reachability Guide for iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790957/reachability-guide-for-ios-4)

reachability should be added whereever u r going to access the network.otherwise apple may reject ur app.if u want to test particularly ur host then use call back connection failed with error callback to display some alertview with error or make ur own message.

Comment: Not much use just giving him a link without any comment. Particularly as it isn't reachability he's concerned with, but whether or a *particularly* site can be reached.