# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) error

Tags: iphone, ios, linker, mach-o

Got this error for the first time, I have looked around and cannot find a solution to help me, I have cleaned my build and also checked to make sure I am compiling for the latest firmware.

This happened after I tired implementing a reachability solution I found over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790957/reachability-guide-for-ios-4) 
I imported the two reachability files (.m/.h) then added this code into the .m file and delared t in the . h of the reachability files

```
-(BOOL)reachable {
    Reachability*r =[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"enbr.co.cc"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus =[r currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus ==NotReachable){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;}
```

After that I called the function from both of my viwcontrollers viewwillappear methods like so..

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    //-- Check Reachability START ---->
    Reachability *reach = [[Reachability alloc] init];

    if ([reach reachable]) {
            NSLog(@"Reachable");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
    }
     //-- Check Reachability END ---->
}
```

No errors were produced untill I tried to build and run in the simulator. This is the error I received :(

> Ld
>   /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/wizcode.app/wizcode
>   normal i386
>       cd "/Users/imac/Documents/Iphone
>   applications/wizsanCode/wizsanCode.5/wizcode"
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   -arch i386 -isysroot
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist
>   /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Intermediates/wizcode.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/wizcode.build/Objects-normal/i386/wizcode.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lz
>   -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework
>   Foundation -o
>   /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/wizcode.app/wizcode
>
> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in
>   /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Intermediates/wizcode.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/wizcode.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-183E2D17A6B26176.o
>   and
>   /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Intermediates/wizcode.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/wizcode.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-183E2D17A6B26176.o
>   for architecture i386 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1 ld: duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in
>   /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Intermediates/wizcode.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/wizcode.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-183E2D17A6B26176.o
>   and
>   /Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wizcode-ccyrqptvfsabmbahgxartbvxwurq/Build/Intermediates/wizcode.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/wizcode.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability-183E2D17A6B26176.o
>   for architecture i386
>
> Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, the problem has been resolved.

What happened was when I imported the reachability files over into my build something funny was happening and somehow I deleted the reachability files that were already in my build being used by the "all seeing I" ASIHTTPRequest methods I was using for transporting my data... which messed everything up.

So long story short I replaced the files and everything is working fine and I also found out that ASIHTTPTequest is taking care of the reachability for me :) how cool is that.

Comment: The Answer I needed!!
 Reachability classes were already among the ShareKit classes that I had in the project!

Comment: This also happens when you import a .m file :(

Comment: This also happens when you have multiple targets and you forget to check all appropriate checkboxes during the Create NSManagedObject Subclass operation.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `SystemConfiguration` is linked properly. Anyway, clean up your code:

```
+ (BOOL)reachable {
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"enbr.co.cc"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    return internetStatus != NotReachable;
}
```

And then just call `[Reachability reachable]` wherever you need. This also fixes a memory leak you have.

Comment: Nope its in their... double triple check.

Comment: Thanks for the memory leak fix, however This Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) error is still there.. I removed all my frameworks and added them back.. what a random error.

Comment: Are you building for both armv6 and armv7 at the same time?

Comment: I am not sure, its not something I have read about before.. What should I be looking for?

Comment: It may also be that you are importing .m instead of .h

Comment: I have managed to find that my architectures>levels> is set to standard(armv6 armv7)

Comment: Well, if you are not importing .m by mistake, try cleaning all targets and building against armv6 only.

Comment: @C.Johns let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1680/discussion-between-anton-and-c-johns)

Comment: I am importing **#import "Reachability.h"** in both

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, it happened me after I regenerated managed subclasses and it didn't actually overwrite the existing ones but just made new duplicates. I just deleted both and regenerated and it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying my core data model, I deleted all the (auto generated) NSManagedObjectModel subclasses, and created them again. Once they all were created, I dragged them to a Group folder in XCode... and got the spinning beachball for longer than usual.

The next time I tried to run, it failed with the "Mach-O-Linker" (Id) Error.  After reading other responses, I figured it might have something to do with the NSMObj classes not being where expected. I deleted them, quit, opened, generated them, and put them in their customary group folder... and Viola! no Mach-O error.

I see that the problem is resolved, but I post this just to index it under the proper question. In my case, deleting and regenerating (via editor menu) the managed object subclasses fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it then add it again. Works for me. :D

Answer (score 0):

This happens with me when i am adding third party analytics framework in my project. When i check with the info of framework its not properly copied on disk. i download new framework and copied it into project and now there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this code in one of my UIViewController and removing it solved this bug. What a stupid and not-clear-at-all error message

```
NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Mode) {
    Assessments = 0,
    Onboarding
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running YourApp.xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj file. I did face the same issue when did run .xcodeproj file. Running .xcworkspace has solved the problem and the error has gone away.