# iOS notification for connection state change disconnect to connect and back

Tags: ios, captivenetwork

Looking for a way to get my IOS app to receive a notification when the device looses connection to the internet.

Any idea if there are notification classes for this?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810585/how-to-get-reachability-notifications-in-ios-in-background-when-dropping-wi-fi-n

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a demo app with a class called [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

I use this and many others do too, it'll do exactly what you ask for in your question.