# iOS - connection fail alert message when no internet connection

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsurlconnection

in my app i want to show an alert message when user has no internet connection i used the below code but it never enters to this block it never fires it never called

how can i control if user has internet connection or not?

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"connect");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:@"check your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

note: i use iOS 5.1 version and i have put my delegates in to the .h file

Comment: make sure this method is in the delegate of your NSURLConnection

Comment: i have the delegates: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html it is in the NSURLConnectionDelegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) Class to check availability of Internet connection. It is much faster than `connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError` Usually it will take 1 minute to fire this method when there is no Internet connection. But the Reachability `block` will fire as soon as the connection switches.

Comment: thanks, i tried to using Reachability class. i add the .m and .h files then how can i use it in my xib file? in viewDidLoad how can i use the Reachability Class to check the availability?

Comment: see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790957/reachability-guide-for-ios-4