# Error when trying to check for internet access with Reachable.h/.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, reachability

I have imported Reachable and followed the chosen anser on this thread: [Reachability Guide for iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790957/reachability-guide-for-ios-4) Everything looks good, apart from a yellow triangle saying "incomplete implementation". Then when I press run I get ten red errors coming from the Reachable.m file, saying things like "ARC forbids explicit message send of release', 'NSAutoReleasePool is unavailable in automatic counting reference mode' and 'Cast of C pointer of type 'void ': to objective-c pointer type 'Reachability' etc. and 'declaration of 'struct sockaddr_in' will not be visible outside of this function [3]' from the Reachable.h file. Any ideas? Maybe the Reachable files are out of date? I have no experience with using C data types etc. and whenever I have to import an extra implementation/header file things seem to go wrong :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's Reachability sample code was last updated in 2010. It doesn't use `ARC` and contains code that is non-trivial to convert to `ARC`.

The solution is simple:

Set the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for that file.

[image: Compiler -fno-obj-arc flag set for Reachability.m]

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a beautiful human being :). I never would have got that :).

Comment: This answer should be +repped, so other people know. I googled for about 3 hours and only found things parallel to the link I posted in the OP....